# Alerts and warnings for Wordpress theme. What are the risks associated?

Tags: wordpress

I have bought a Wordpress theme and scanned its files on www.themecheck.info. The results show 3 critical alerts and 9 warnings:

Alerts:

1. Presence of iframes : iframes are sometimes used to load unwanted
   adverts and malicious code on another site Found  in file vc_gmaps.php. 6: 'link' =>
   'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zy8g7PkInS5s.k1_kczfkJFound  in file content.php. 634:
   $video_block = '';

   2. Malware : Operations on file system file_get_contents was found in the file functions.php 686: $font_json_file
      = file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/fonts/webfonts.json');
   3. Admin menu : Themes should use add_theme_page() for adding admin pages. File class-tgm-plugin-activation.php : 724: $this->page_hook
      = add_submenu_page( $args['parent_slug'], $args['page_title'], $args['menu_tiFile options.php : 5913: $page
      = add_submenu_page('thegem-theme-options',esc_html__('TheGem Theme Options','File image-generator.php : 187: add_submenu_page(null,
      esc_html__('TheGem thumbnails','thegem'),
      esc_html__File functions.php : 121: $page
      = add_menu_page(esc_html__('TheGem','thegem'), esc_html__('TheGem','thegem'),File functions.php : 1876: $page
      = add_submenu_page('thegem-theme-options', esc_html__('Self-Hosted Fonts','th2135: $page = add_submenu_page(NULL, esc_html__('Add new
      social network','thegem'), '', 'File functions.php : 1876: $page
      = add_submenu_page('thegem-theme-options', esc_html__('Self-Hosted Fonts','th2135: $page = add_submenu_page(NULL, esc_html__('Add new
      social network','thegem'), '', '

Warnings:

1. Text domain : Incorrect use of translation functions.Found a
   translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function __,
   with the arguments 'Save my name, email, and website in this browser
   for the next time I comment.' in
   file single-product-reviews.php.Found a translation function that is
   missing a text-domain. Function __, with the arguments 'Save my
   name, email, and website in this browser for the next time I
   comment.' in file comments.php.More than one text-domain is being
   used in this theme. This means the theme will not be compatible with
   WordPress.org language packs. The domains found are woocommerce,
   thegem, yith-woocommerce-wishlist, tgmpa, default, contact-form-7.

   2. PHP short tags : Presence of PHP short tagsPHP short tags were found in file lazy-items.class.php. "This practice is discouraged
      because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag
      php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with
      the --enable-short-tags option" (php.net), which is not the case on
      many servers.56: visibilityOffset:
      visibilityOffset)?>,
   3. Line endings consistency : Both DOS and UNIX style line endingsFound a mix of \r\n and \n line endings in
      file style-editor.css.Found a mix of \r\n and \n line endings in
      file thegem-itemsAnimations.css.Found a mix of \r\n and \n line
      endings in file thegem-itemsAnimations.js.Found a mix of \r\n and \n
      line endings in file jquery.juraSlider.js.
   4. Custom elements : Presence of custom headerNo reference to custom header was found in the theme.
   5. Custom elements : Presence of custom backgroundNo reference to custom background was found in the theme.
   6. I18N implementation : Proper use of _x(Possible variable $v found in translation function in functions.php. Translation function calls
      should not contain PHP variables.
   7. CSS files : Presence of Author URICould not find Author URI.
   8. Date and time implementation : Use of the_date()At least one hard coded date was found in the file content.php. Function get_option(
      'date_format' ) should be used instead.
   9. Screenshot : Screenshot fileBad screenshot file extension ! File screenshot.png is not an actual JPG file. Detected type was
      : "image/png".

Can anybody comment what are the risks of using this theme? Is it better to choose another one? The developer says that the theme is safe to use, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is the theme a php page you add on your server?

Comment: Most likely, if I understand your question correctly. It consists of many php files and would be installed to the Wordpress site.